# Add spaces using kotlin string functions/string format

Tags: string, kotlin, replaceall, string.format

This might been asked here couple of times.. what i am trying to do adding space between every four char of a string(8888319024981442). my string length is exactly 16.   `String.format` is not helpful

avoiding the usage of split or creating multiple strings in memory.

is there any kotlin function/String.format that can be quickly used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there is a very simple way to do this, but there is the traditional one:

```
val number = "8888319024981442"
val list = mutableListOf<String>()
for (i in 0..3) { list.add(number.substring(i*4, (i+1)*4))}
println(list.joinToString(" "))
```

**EDIT**

Or @IR42 simple answer

```
number.chunked(4).joinToString(separator = " ")
```

Comment: `number.chunked(4).joinToString(separator = " ")`

Comment: I think your first method creates a temporary `ArrayList`, an `IntRange`, and four sub-`String`s in addition to the necessary `StringBuilder` and result `String`…

Comment: For number, which doesn't contain an exact multiple of 4 it's better to use
number.reversed().chunked(4).joinToString(" ").reversed()
It shows "123 4567" instead of wrong "1234 567"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an answer which is both simple and elegant *and* avoids all temporary objects.

For the former, IR42's use of `chunked()` is probably best.

Here's a stab at the latter:

```
val number = "8888319024981442"
val result = buildString {
    for (i in 0 until number.length) {
        if (i % 4 == 0 && i > 0)
            append(' ')
        append(number[i])
    }
}
println(result) // '8888 3190 2498 1442'
```

This creates only a single `StringBuilder`, and then a single `String` from it — which is the minimum possible*.  It's a bit ugly and long-winded, but if avoiding all temporary objects is really important**, then that's probably about the best you can do.

(* Or at least, the minimum possible given the conditions.  For better performance, consider passing the `StringBuilder` itself on without creating a `String` from it.  Even better, use an existing `StringBuilder` in instead of creating one at all.  But of course all that needs changes to the surrounding code.)

(** While there are situations in which this *is* really important, in practice they're pretty unusual.  I'd [recommend](https://www.defprogramming.com/quotes-by/michael-a-jackson/) going with the simple version until you've done some profiling and proved that this is a bottleneck and that the complex version really does perform better in your case.  And even then, fold it into a utility function to keep the main code clear.)